# Keeping your Tzitzis out as a segulah for shemiras einayim - Mishnah Berurah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzitzis, segulah, mishnah-berurah, shemirat-eynayim

I've heard that there is a *Mishnah Berurah* that says that keeping one's *Tzitzis*  out is a *Segulah* (protection or virtue) for *Shemiras Einayim* (to protect once eyes, i.e., not to look at prohibited things). Does anyone have the source for it?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69839/759

Comment: I wonder if the mere fact that the Torah mentions in the section regarding tzitzit - "You shall see it and remember all of G-d's mitzvoth"? Wouldn't that, alone, be sufficient proof?

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah Berurah ([24:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=62)) mentions this as a *segulah* of the *mitzvah* of *tzitzit* in general:

> ומצוה זו מציל האדם מן החטא דכתיב ולא תתורו וגו' למען תזכרו וגו' והייתם קדושים ואף דכל שאר המצות אין בהם זאת הסגולה להצילו מיצה"ר ציצית עדיף וכדאיתא בעובדא דמנחות (מ"ד ע"א) מעשה באדם אחד וכו
>
> And this *mitzvah* saves man from sin, as it is written "and you shall not go astray etc." "in order that you remember etc." "and you shall be holy". And even though all other *mitzvot* do not have this *segulah* to save him from the evil inclination, *tzitzit* is superior as in the incident in Menachot (44a) "an incident with a certain man etc".

The incident referenced is the following:

**[Menachot 44a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=44&format=pdf)**

> מעשה באדם אחד שהיה זהיר במצות ציצית שמע שיש זונה בכרכי הים שנוטלת ד' מאות זהובים בשכרה שיגר לה ארבע מאות זהובים וקבע לה זמן כשהגיע זמנו בא וישב על הפתח נכנסה שפחתה ואמרה לה אותו אדם ששיגר ליך ד' מאות זהובים בא וישב על הפתח אמרה היא יכנס נכנס הציעה לו ז' מטות שש של כסף ואחת של זהב ובין כל אחת ואחת סולם של כסף ועליונה של זהב עלתה וישבה על גבי עליונה כשהיא ערומה ואף הוא עלה לישב ערום כנגדה באו ד' ציציותיו וטפחו לו על פניו נשמט וישב לו ע"ג קרקע ואף היא נשמטה וישבה ע"ג קרקע אמרה לו גפה של רומי שאיני מניחתך עד שתאמר לי מה מום ראית בי אמר לה העבודה שלא ראיתי אשה יפה כמותך אלא מצוה אחת ציונו ה' אלהינו וציצית שמה וכתיב בה אני ה' אלהיכם שתי פעמים אני הוא שעתיד ליפרע ואני הוא שעתיד לשלם שכר עכשיו נדמו עלי כד' עדים אמרה לו איני מניחך עד שתאמר לי מה שמך ומה שם עירך ומה שם רבך ומה שם מדרשך שאתה למד בו תורה כתב ונתן בידה עמדה וחילקה כל נכסיה שליש למלכות ושליש לעניים ושליש נטלה בידה חוץ מאותן מצעות ובאת לבית מדרשו של ר'  חייא אמרה לו רבי צוה עלי ויעשוני גיורת אמר לה בתי שמא עיניך נתת באחד מן התלמידים הוציאה כתב מידה ונתנה לו אמר לה לכי זכי במקחך אותן מצעות שהציעה לו באיסור הציעה לו בהיתר
>
> Once a man, who was very scrupulous about the
>   precept of zizith, heard of a certain harlot in one of the towns by the sea who accepted four hundred
>   gold [denars] for her hire. He sent her four hundred gold [denars] and appointed a day with her.
>   When the day arrived he came and waited at her door, and her maid came and told her, ‘That man
>   who sent you four hundred gold [denars] is here and waiting at the door’; to which she replied ‘Let
>   him come in’. When he came in she prepared for him seven beds, six of silver and one of gold; and
>   between one bed and the other there were steps of silver, but the last were of gold. She then went up
>   to the top bed and lay down upon it naked. He too went up after her in his desire to sit naked with
>   her, when all of a sudden the four fringes [of his garment] struck him across the face; whereupon he
>   slipped off and sat upon the ground. She also slipped off and sat upon the ground and said, ‘By the
>   Roman Capitol, I will not leave you alone until you tell me what blemish you saw in me. ‘By the
>   Temple’, he replied, ‘never have I seen a woman as beautiful as you are; but there is one precept
>   which the Lord our God has commanded us, it is called zizith, and with regard to it the expression ‘I
>   am the Lord your God’ is twice written, signifying, I am He who will exact punishment in the
>   future, and I am He who will give reward in the future. Now [the zizith] appeared to me as four
>   witnesses [testifying against me]’. She said, ‘I will not leave you until you tell me your name, the
>   name of your town, the name of your teacher, the name of your school in which you study the
>   Torah’. He wrote all this down and handed it to her. Thereupon she arose and divided her estate into
>   three parts; one third for the government, one third to be distributed among the poor, and one third
>   she took with her in her hand; the bed clothes, however, she retained. She then came to the Beth
>   Hamidrash of R. Hiyya, and said to him, ‘Master, give instructions about me that they make me a
>   proselyte’. ‘My daughter’, he replied; ‘perhaps you have set your eyes on one of the disciples?’ She
>   thereupon took out the script and handed it to him. ‘Go’, said he ‘and enjoy your acquisition’. Those
>   very bed-clothes which she had spread for him for an illicit purpose she now spread out for him
>   lawfully. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf))